# Discord bot being able to send message even if not correctly called

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot but I want to find out how I would make it so that if a user leaves something empty without calling it correctly, it would still send a message. By this I mean, if someone does //changelogs (number), the bot would send the changelogs of this version if the user puts in a number in (number). However, if the user just calls //changelogs, it would display a message of what versions of changelogs the user can call.

Comment: Have you heard about optional arguments? Or default values for them?

Answer (score 0):

```
@commands.command()
async def changelogs(ctx: Context, number: int = None):
    if number is None:
        await ctx.send("a message of what versions of changelogs the user can call")
    else:
        await ctx.send("the changelogs of this version")
```

References :

`commands.command` : https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20command#discord.ext.commands.command

`Context` : https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context

Typing : https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html